# Do a translate followed by a rotate followed by a translate

Tags: python

(This is just a basic example).
I want to translate, then rotate and then translate again (in local).

At the moment I have this:

```
import bpy 
import  mathutils

object = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]


# translate
translation = mathutils.Vector((5.0, 0.0, 0.0))

inv = object.matrix_world.copy()
inv.invert()
vec_rot = translation * inv
object.location = object.location + vec_rot

# rotate
euler = mathutils.Euler((0.0, 0.0, 45.0))
object.rotation_euler.rotate(euler)


# translate again
translation = mathutils.Vector((5.0, 0.0, 0.0))

inv = object.matrix_world.copy()
inv.invert()
vec_rot = translation * inv
object.location = object.location + vec_rot
```

The problem is that this works as the 2 translates combined followed by the rotate.
What I expect is to have the object first move in the x, then rotate, and then move in it's rotated direction.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can also obtain the equivalent of keystrokes gxx5 rzz45 gxx5, (ie local transform on x by 5, rotate on z by 45 degrees, local transform again by 5), by creating [transform](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.Translation) and [rotation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.Rotation) matrices, and chaining them together via matrix multiplication in the order wanted.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import radians

# Translation matrices
T0 = T1 = Matrix.Translation((5, 0, 0))

# Rotation matrix
R0 = Matrix.Rotation(radians(45), 4, 'Z')

obj = bpy.context.object

#  
M = T0 * R0 * T1

obj.matrix_world = M * obj.matrix_world
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

What you're missing is a scene update before the 2nd translation. It will recalculate the local matrix before applying the 2nd translation and thus leads to the result you're aiming for:

```
import bpy 
import  mathutils

object = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]


# translate
translation = mathutils.Vector((5.0, 0.0, 0.0))

inv = object.matrix_world.copy()
inv.invert()
vec_rot = translation * inv
object.location = object.location + vec_rot

# rotate
euler = mathutils.Euler((0.0, 0.0, 45.0))
object.rotation_euler.rotate(euler)

###### SCENE UPDATE ######    
bpy.context.scene.update()
##########################

# translate again
translation = mathutils.Vector((5.0, 0.0, 0.0))

inv = object.matrix_world.copy()
inv.invert()
vec_rot = translation * inv
object.location = object.location + vec_rot
```

Comment: Is it possible to only update a certain part of the scene?

Comment: @clankill3r I tried several object / mesh related update methods and none worked. So far seems like the only way as far as I'm aware.